# Huawei MateBook D 16 with Ubuntu 22.04 wakes up from suspend improperly

Tags: suspend, 22.04, huawei

I bought a Huawei MateBook D 16 laptop. It is shipped with Windows 11 from the vendor and worked as expected. After installing Ubuntu 22.04 and all the latest updates I'm experiencing an issue. It doesn't wake up properly when I'm closing and opening the lid. I log in to my workspace and can do nothing. If Chrome browser was open, it doesn't respond and disappear on my actions. Ubuntu menu doesn't show up. I can't launch any program. I googled solutions, but nothing helped. Only a hard reboot (keeping the power button pushed) helps, but it's not convenient for everyday usage.

System and hardware information:

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 5.15.0-56-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-004) (gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38) #62-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 22 19:54:14 UTC 2022

$ hostnamectl
 Static hostname: pwm
       Icon name: computer-laptop
         Chassis: laptop
      Machine ID: 7*8
         Boot ID: 9*9
Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS              
          Kernel: Linux 5.15.0-56-generic
    Architecture: x86-64
 Hardware Vendor: HUAWEI
  Hardware Model: RLEF-XX

$ sudo lshw -short
[sudo] password for tenux: 
H/W path        Device          Class          Description
==========================================================
                                system         RLEF-XX (C170)
/0                              bus            RLEF-XX-PCB
/0/0                            memory         128KiB BIOS
/0/4                            processor      12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-12700H
/0/4/a                          memory         512KiB L1 cache
/0/4/b                          memory         4MiB L2 cache
/0/4/c                          memory         24MiB L3 cache
/0/5                            memory         288KiB L1 cache
/0/6                            memory         192KiB L1 cache
/0/7                            memory         7680KiB L2 cache
/0/8                            memory         24MiB L3 cache
/0/9                            memory         256KiB L1 cache
/0/15                           memory         16GiB System Memory
/0/15/0                         memory         2GiB Row of chips LPDDR4 Synchronous 4267 MHz (0,2 ns)
/0/15/1                         memory         2GiB Row of chips LPDDR4 Synchronous 4267 MHz (0,2 ns)
/0/15/2                         memory         2GiB Row of chips LPDDR4 Synchronous 4267 MHz (0,2 ns)
/0/15/3                         memory         2GiB Row of chips LPDDR4 Synchronous 4267 MHz (0,2 ns)
/0/15/4                         memory         2GiB Row of chips LPDDR4 Synchronous 4267 MHz (0,2 ns)
/0/15/5                         memory         2GiB Row of chips LPDDR4 Synchronous 4267 MHz (0,2 ns)
/0/15/6                         memory         2GiB Row of chips LPDDR4 Synchronous 4267 MHz (0,2 ns)
/0/15/7                         memory         2GiB Row of chips LPDDR4 Synchronous 4267 MHz (0,2 ns)
/0/100                          bridge         12th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
/0/100/2        /dev/fb0        display        Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics Controller
/0/100/4                        generic        Alder Lake Innovation Platform Framework Processor Partici
/0/100/6                        bridge         12th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x4 Controller #0
/0/100/6/0      /dev/nvme0      storage        PCIe-8 SSD 512GB
/0/100/6/0/0    hwmon3          disk           NVMe disk
/0/100/6/0/2    /dev/ng0n1      disk           NVMe disk
/0/100/6/0/1    /dev/nvme0n1    disk           512GB NVMe disk
/0/100/6/0/1/1  /dev/nvme0n1p1  volume         511MiB Windows FAT volume
/0/100/6/0/1/2  /dev/nvme0n1p2  volume         1709MiB EXT4 volume
/0/100/6/0/1/3  /dev/nvme0n1p3  volume         474GiB EFI partition
/0/100/8                        generic        12th Gen Core Processor Gaussian & Neural Accelerator
/0/100/a                        generic        Platform Monitoring Technology
/0/100/d                        bus            Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller
/0/100/d/0      usb1            bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/d/1      usb2            bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14                       bus            Alder Lake PCH USB 3.2 xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0     usb3            bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/1   input6          input          2.4G Mouse
/0/100/14/0/3                   generic        USB Type-C Digital AV Adapter
/0/100/14/0/7   input9          multimedia     Integrated Webcam_FHD: Integrat
/0/100/14/0/a                   communication  AX201 Bluetooth
/0/100/14/1     usb4            bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14.2                     memory         RAM memory
/0/100/14.3     wlp0s20f3       network        Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi
/0/100/15                       bus            Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0
/0/100/15.1                     bus            Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1
/0/100/16                       communication  Alder Lake PCH HECI Controller
/0/100/19                       bus            Alder Lake-P Serial IO I2C Controller #0
/0/100/19.1                     bus            Alder Lake-P Serial IO I2C Controller #1
/0/100/1e                       communication  Alder Lake PCH UART #0
/0/100/1e.2                     bus            Intel Corporation
/0/100/1f                       bridge         Alder Lake PCH eSPI Controller
/0/100/1f/0                     system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/1                     system         PnP device PNP0b00
/0/100/1f/2                     system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/3                     input          PnP device PNP0303
/0/100/1f/4                     system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/5                     system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/6                     system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f.3     card0           multimedia     Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller
/0/100/1f.4                     bus            Alder Lake PCH-P SMBus Host Controller
/0/100/1f.5                     bus            Alder Lake-P PCH SPI Controller
/1                              power          HB5781P1EEW-31
/2              input0          input          Lid Switch
/3              input1          input          Power Button
/4              input10         input          Huawei WMI hotkeys
/5              input11         input          GXTP7863:00 27C6:01E0 Mouse
/6              input12         input          GXTP7863:00 27C6:01E0 Touchpad
/7              input14         input          sof-hda-dsp Mic
/8              input15         input          sof-hda-dsp Headphone
/9              input16         input          sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=3
/a              input17         input          sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=4
/b              input18         input          sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=5
/c              input2          input          AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
/d              input8          input          Video Bus
```

During the last two crashes, I pressed Ctrl + Alt + F1 (or F2) and took photos of log messages:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I currently have the same issue on the same laptop. It seems to be caused by the SSD not waking up properly from suspend. I had some luck and got it working yesterday, but I cannot reproduce it.

For now, a good workaround is using hibernation instead of suspend, but this might wear down the SSD over time.

Comment: Yes, suspend turn out not stable solution for this case. The hibernation have been working properly for me for the last four months.
Why do you think it might wear down the SSD over time?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I have the same issue ([(23.04) OS crashes after waking from suspend/reopening lid](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1472616/23-04-os-crashes-after-waking-from-suspend-reopening-lid)).
Have you managed fixing the suspend function? If not, how do you make ubuntu go hibernate instead of suspend? I tried hibernate from console and it just shut down my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with my Huawei Matebook D16 RLEF-X.

In my case, the issue relates to the dmesg message (tested and received in USB-live OS)

```
nvme 0000:01:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
```

The good news are that I have found a solution.
The bad news -- it requires to patch and recompile the kernel.

---

The kernel patch consists of forcefully disabling ability to put the NVMe into the D3cold state.

Inside the kernel sources in the file `drivers/pci/quirks.c` I put the line:

```c
DECLARE_PCI_FIXUP_CLASS_EARLY(0x126f, PCI_ANY_ID,
                              0x0108, 8, quirk_no_ata_d3);
```

after the similar line for `PCI_VENDOR_ID_VIA`.

The "magic numbers" 0x126f and 0x0108 are VENDOR_ID and CLASS_ID, respectively. They can be obtained using `lspci -nn` command:

```
lspci -nn | grep Non-V
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Silicon Motion, Inc. Device [126f:1001] (rev 03)
                                        ^^^^                                ^^^^
```

---

Unfortunately, I could not provide a complete kernel recompilation guide for Ubuntu. Maybe [the "BuildYourOwnKernel" topic](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) could help.

Full research (maybe will be helpful for someone) on the NVMe suspending issue on the Huawei laptop is located on [my GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/Toliak/86340b839b45f2c6fa4337ba6d8e971b)