# (23.04) OS crashes after waking from suspend/reopening lid

Tags: suspend, laptop, crash, 23.04, lid

I recently bought Huawei MateBook d16 (on intel i5 12450H, LPDDR4x) and did clean install of Ubuntu 23.04.

Everything is great except when I resume from suspend or when I reopen the lid, the OS either freezes or it completely crashes.

[image: Photo]

Things I tried to fix this after googling:

1. Turning off Bluetooth in BIOS
2. Turning off Fingerprint Scanner in BIOS
3. Setting BIOS Setting "Other Wakeup Source" to Disabled
4. Setting BIOS Setting "Virtualization Technology" to Disabled
5. sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
6. Updating Intel graphics drivers
7. Following this post https://askubuntu.com/a/1009393/1705081

[System-info](https://pastebin.com/QPVEQZ6H)

```
Starting the Ubuntu Forums 'system-info' Report: 2023-06-15  13:07:31 MSK (+0300)
    Part of the Ama-gi Project
    Version: 02.00-08, Script Date: 2023.05.24
 
---------------------------------------------------------------
Main Complaint: Crash after suspend
Problem Description:  Laptop crashes after waking from suspend or reopening the lid
---------- General Computer Specifications:
 
  --- Computer/CPU Information from 'lshw -C cpu' --- 
*-Cpu
    Description: CPU
    Product: 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-12450H
    Vendor: Intel Corp.
    Physical id: 4
    Bus info: cpu@0
    Version: 6.154.3
    Slot: CPU0
    Size: 4150MHz
    Capacity: 4400MHz
    Width: 64 bits
    Clock: 100MHz
    Capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 
        apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse 
        sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc art 
        arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid 
        aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx 
        est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe 
        popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 
        3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp 
        ibrs_enhanced tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase 
        tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rdseed adx smap clflushopt 
        clwb intel_pt sha_ni xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves split_lock_detect 
        avx_vnni dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp 
        hwp_pkg_req hfi umip pku ospke waitpkg gfni vaes vpclmulqdq rdpid 
        movdiri movdir64b fsrm md_clear serialize arch_lbr ibt flush_l1d 
        arch_capabilities cpufreq
    Configuration: cores=8 enabledcores=8 microcode=1065 threads=12
 
computer
    Description: Notebook
    Product: RLEF-XX (C170)
    Vendor: HUAWEI
    Version: M1010
    Serial: [REMOVED]
    Width: 64 bits
    Capabilities: smbios-3.4.0 dmi-3.4.0 smp vsyscall32
    Configuration:
        chassis=notebook
        family=MateBook D
        sku=C170
        uuid=[REMOVED]
 
------------------ SMBIOS Information from '/sys/class/dmi/id/' 
Bios Vendor:         HUAWEI
Bios Version:        1.24
Bios Release:        1.24
Board Vendor:        HUAWEI
Board Name:          RLEF-XX-PCB
Board Version:       M1010
Board Serial:        PM04C02327000241
Board Asset Tag:     N/A
 
Current boot mode:   UEFI Firmware mode
   --- SecureBoot Status from 'mokutil':
SecureBoot disabled
Platform is in Setup Mode
 
 
---------- Memory Information:
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15703        2996       10981         701        2751       12707
Swap:           4095           0        4095
 
---------- Swap Information:
  --- Info from 'fstab'
/swap.img   none    swap    sw  0   0
 
  --- Info from '/proc/swaps'
Filename                Type        Size        Used        Priority
/swap.img                               file        4194300     0       -2
 
  --- System Swapiness Settings
Valid swappiness settings are from 10 - 60 . 
Current setting in '/proc/sys/vm/swappiness': 60 
Current configuration setting in '/etc/sysctl.conf file: 
 
 
---------- IP Address Information:
  --- IP Address Information from 'ip addr' --- 
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    inet [REMOVED]
    inet6 [REMOVED]
2: wlp0s20f3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet [REMOVED]
    inet6 [REMOVED]
 
  --- Internet Connection Status from 'ping [various addresses]' --- 
Connected to Internet with DNS
 
  --- Network Device Status Summary from 'ip addr' ---  
These Network Devices are up:
2: wlp0s20f3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
 
For more detailed wireless information, get and run the script at https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info 
 
  --- Hostname from 'hostname --fqdn' ---  
The 'Hostname' of the computer system is: kostya-RLEF-XX
 
 
---------- Storage Controller Information From 'lspci':
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Silicon Motion, Inc. Device 1001 (rev 03) (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
    Subsystem: Silicon Motion, Inc. Device 2262
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16, NUMA node 0
    Memory at 80400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable+ 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=16 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [158] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [178] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [180] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme
 
 
---------- File system specs from 'df -h':
Filesystem                        Type  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ext4  466G   31G  411G   7% /
/dev/nvme0n1p2                    ext4  2,0G  110M  1,7G   6% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1                    vfat  1,1G   18M  1,1G   2% /boot/efi
 
---------- Disk/Partition Information From 'fdisk':
 
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 476,94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk model: PCIe-8 SSD 512GB                        
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 42DB227A-088A-3A4D-8BBB-3B847CA7CF92
 
Device           Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048    2203647   2201600     1G EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 2203648    6397951   4194304     2G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3 6397952 1000212479 993814528 473,9G Linux filesystem
 
Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: 473,89 GiB, 508831989760 bytes, 993812480 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
 
 
---------- Disk/Partition Information From 'lsblk':
NAME                        SIZE FSTYPE      LABEL MOUNTPOINT                          MODEL
nvme0n1                   476,9G                                                       PCIe-8 SSD 512GB
|_nvme0n1p1                   1G vfat              /boot/efi                           
|_nvme0n1p2                   2G ext4              /boot                               
|_nvme0n1p3               473,9G LVM2_member                                           
  `-ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 473,9G ext4              /                                   
   ------- 'lsblk' information continued ...
NAME                      HOTPLUG PARTUUID                             UUID
nvme0n1                         0                                      
|_nvme0n1p1                     0 99abc21d-3f67-ef4f-ae10-e59f0df7b373 D6EC-709C
|_nvme0n1p2                     0 00a2e2a9-a300-674a-9a5a-5fcd329a48e6 d3f1a5bb-9ab6-45cb-9937-97d350568cd9
|_nvme0n1p3                     0 f2898fdb-4a1a-1e4c-a25a-10814eeed9df YaiNwF-7N5E-lW7X-08kH-3hDQ-Qv0S-VF9ePY
  `-ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv       0                                      f8ec66d3-dd3d-4363-b5cc-9cf6a5728c78
 
----------  BTRFS Information:
There are no BTRFS vdev's present.
 
----------  LVM2 Information:
LVM2 is installed.
 
  PV             VG        Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree DevSize  PV UUID                               
  /dev/nvme0n1p3 ubuntu-vg lvm2 a--  <473,89g    0  <473,89g YaiNwF-7N5E-lW7X-08kH-3hDQ-Qv0S-VF9ePY
 
  PV /dev/nvme0n1p3   VG ubuntu-vg       lvm2 [<473,89 GiB / 0    free]
  Total: 1 [<473,89 GiB] / in use: 1 [<473,89 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
 
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/nvme0n1p3
  VG Name               ubuntu-vg
  PV Size               <473,89 GiB / not usable 0   
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4,00 MiB
  Total PE              121315
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          121315
  PV UUID               YaiNwF-7N5E-lW7X-08kH-3hDQ-Qv0S-VF9ePY
 
  --- Physical Segments ---
  Physical extent 0 to 121314:
    Logical volume  /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
    Logical extents 0 to 121314
 
 
  VG        Attr   Ext   #PV #LV #SN VSize    VFree VG UUID                                VProfile
  ubuntu-vg wz--n- 4,00m   1   1   0 <473,89g    0  LmjELv-n8Bh-eOxo-mUop-Mz8J-HIl9-TXIhO5         
 
  Found volume group "ubuntu-vg" using metadata type lvm2
 
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               ubuntu-vg
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  2
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               1
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <473,89 GiB
  PE Size               4,00 MiB
  Total PE              121315
  Alloc PE / Size       121315 / <473,89 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               LmjELv-n8Bh-eOxo-mUop-Mz8J-HIl9-TXIhO5
 
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
  LV Name                ubuntu-lv
  VG Name                ubuntu-vg
  LV UUID                turVcM-I8Rh-3lHj-eZxH-qI5b-gGnw-adsHoX
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu, 2023-03-20 17:28:10 +0300
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                <473,89 GiB
  Current LE             121315
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0
 
  --- Physical volumes ---
  PV Name               /dev/nvme0n1p3     
  PV UUID               YaiNwF-7N5E-lW7X-08kH-3hDQ-Qv0S-VF9ePY
  PV Status             allocatable
  Total PE / Free PE    121315 / 0
 
 
  LV        Type   Devices          
  ubuntu-lv linear /dev/nvme0n1p3(0)
 
  ACTIVE            '/dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv' [<473,89 GiB] inherit
 
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
  LV Name                ubuntu-lv
  VG Name                ubuntu-vg
  LV UUID                turVcM-I8Rh-3lHj-eZxH-qI5b-gGnw-adsHoX
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu, 2023-03-20 17:28:10 +0300
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                <473,89 GiB
  Current LE             121315
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0
 
 
----------  mdadm RAID Information:
No active md devices present.
---------- Mount Details of '/etc/fstab':
/dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-LVM-LmjELvn8BheOxomUopMz8JHIl9TXIhO5turVcMI8Rh3lHjeZxHqI5bgGnwadsHoX / ext4 defaults 0 1
/dev/disk/by-uuid/d3f1a5bb-9ab6-45cb-9937-97d350568cd9 /boot ext4 defaults 0 1
/dev/disk/by-uuid/D6EC-709C /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1
/swap.img   none    swap    sw  0   0
 
---------- Current Mount Details of 'mount':
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv on / type ext4 (rw,relatime)
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv on /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell type ext4 (ro,noexec,noatime)
/dev/nvme0n1p1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/nvme0n1p2 on /boot type ext4 (rw,relatime)
 
For more detailed disk Information, please run the 'boot-info' script 
from: (STABLE) https://launchpad.net/~yannubuntu/+archive/ubuntu/boot-repair 
 
---------- USB Information from 'lsusb -t -v':
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
    ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/3p, 20000M/x2
    ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
    ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        ID 046d:c542 Logitech, Inc. 
    |__ Port 7: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        ID 0408:1060 Quanta Computer, Inc. 
    |__ Port 7: Dev 3, If 2, Class=Application Specific Interface, Driver=, 480M
        ID 0408:1060 Quanta Computer, Inc. 
    |__ Port 7: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        ID 0408:1060 Quanta Computer, Inc. 
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
    ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
 
---------- Video Details from 'lshw':
 
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Alder Lake-P GT1 [UHD Graphics]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 0c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=1920x1200 resolution=1920,1200 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1200
       resources: 
           iomemory:600-5ff 
           iomemory:400-3ff 
           irq:155 
           memory:6000000000-6000ffffff 
           memory:4000000000-400fffffff 
           ioport:3000(size=64) 
           memory:c0000-dffff 
           memory:4010000000-4016ffffff 
           memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
 
   --- Graphics Environment Continued from 'various graphics ENVs' ----
The Current Configured Destop is: ubuntu:GNOME 
The Current Desktop Session is: ubuntu 
The Current X Desktop Information Details from 'xrandr' are: 
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1920 x 1200, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected primary 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 350mm x 220mm
The Current Session Type is: wayland 
The Current Display Manager is: gdm3
The Current Desktop Theme: 'Yaru-viridian'
The Current Virtual TTY's being used are:
    TTY#    Used By
    tty2    gdm-wayland-ses
    tty2    gnome-session-b
    pts/0   bash
    pts/1   system-info
    pts/1   system-info
    pts/1   sed
    pts/1   system-info
    pts/1   ps
    pts/1   awk
 
---------- Sound Device Information From 'lspci':
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 156
    Memory at 6001138000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 6001000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
 
 
For more detailed audio information, get and run the script at: http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh 
 
---------- Repository Information from '/etc/apt/sources.list and etc/apt/sources.list.d/':
 
Sources List:
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security multiverse
 
Sources List from SourcesD:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam-stable.list.save:
deb [arch=amd64,i386 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/steam.gpg] https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ stable steam
deb-src [arch=amd64,i386 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/steam.gpg] https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ stable steam
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam-beta.list.save:
File had no entries.
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/oibaf-ubuntu-graphics-drivers-lunar.list:
deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu/ lunar main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam-stable.list:
deb [arch=amd64,i386 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/steam.gpg] https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ stable steam
deb-src [arch=amd64,i386 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/steam.gpg] https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ stable steam
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list.save:
deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf] http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:
deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam-beta.list:
File had no entries.
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/oibaf-ubuntu-graphics-drivers-lunar.list.save:
deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu/ lunar main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list.save:
deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:
deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf] http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable main
 
---------- KeyMap and Locale Information from from various sources:
   --- Keymap Info from 'setxkbmap' ----
WARNING: Running setxkbmap against an XWayland server
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us
 
   --- Locale Info from 'localectl' ----
System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
               LANGUAGE=en
               LC_NUMERIC=ru_RU.UTF-8
               LC_TIME=ru_RU.UTF-8
               LC_MONETARY=ru_RU.UTF-8
               LC_PAPER=ru_RU.UTF-8
               LC_NAME=ru_RU.UTF-8
               LC_ADDRESS=ru_RU.UTF-8
               LC_TELEPHONE=ru_RU.UTF-8
               LC_MEASUREMENT=ru_RU.UTF-8
               LC_IDENTIFICATION=ru_RU.UTF-8
    VC Keymap: (unset)
   X11 Layout: gb
    X11 Model: pc105
 
---------- Other Details from 'Various':
The current kernel version is:       6.2.0-20-generic 
    --- Operating System Release Description --- 
The current release description is:  Ubuntu 23.04 
 
Original Installation Date:          2023-03-20+17:21:47 
Original Installation Media: Ubuntu 23.04 "Lunar Lobster" - Release amd64 (20230418)
Do-Release-Upgrade Date: This system may have not had a 'Release Upgrade' through 'do-release-upgrade'
 
   --- Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) Informationt:
These are the current kernel ranges for HWE kernels for this release.
   --- HWE Kernel Reference from 'apt-cache show':
For HWE Package: linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04, Kernel Version: 6.2.0.20.20
 
   --- HWE Package Status from 'dpkg':
Package linux-generic-hwe-22.04 is installed.
 
   --- Certified Hardware Platform Status: (By the Ubuntu Wiki Standards)
Ubuntu Certified Hardware Platform. Safe to install 
the Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE).
 
   --- User Installed Package List:
bsdutils
cloud-init
code
dash
diffutils
efibootmgr
findutils
fonts-indic
gnome-user-docs-ru
google-chrome-stable
grep
grub-efi-amd64
grub-efi-amd64-signed
gzip
hostname
hunspell-en-au
hunspell-en-ca
hunspell-en-gb
hunspell-en-za
hyphen-en-ca
hyphen-en-gb
hyphen-en-us
hyphen-ru
ibus-table-cangjie-big
ibus-table-cangjie3
ibus-table-cangjie5
init
language-pack-en
language-pack-en-base
language-pack-gnome-en
language-pack-gnome-en-base
language-pack-gnome-ru
language-pack-gnome-ru-base
language-pack-ru
language-pack-ru-base
libc6
libc6:i386
libchewing3
libchewing3-data
libegl1
libegl1:i386
libgbm1
libgbm1:i386
libgl1
libgl1-mesa-dri
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
libgl1:i386
libm17n-0
libmarisa0
libopencc-data
libopencc1.1
libotf1
libpinyin-data
libpinyin15
libreoffice-help-common
libreoffice-help-en-gb
libreoffice-help-en-us
libreoffice-help-ru
libreoffice-l10n-en-gb
libreoffice-l10n-en-za
libreoffice-l10n-ru
linux-generic-hwe-22.04
login
lvm2
m17n-db
mythes-en-au
mythes-en-us
mythes-ru
ncurses-base
ncurses-bin
shim-signed
steam-launcher
steam-libs-amd64
steam-libs-i386:i386
thunderbird-locale-en
thunderbird-locale-en-gb
thunderbird-locale-en-us
thunderbird-locale-ru
thunderbird-locale-zh-hant
ubuntu-desktop
ubuntu-desktop-minimal
ubuntu-minimal
ubuntu-standard
ubuntu-wallpapers
util-linux
util-linux-extra
wbritish
wpasupplicant
zoom
 
   --- Installed Snap Package List:
bare
bovo
core18
core22
firefox
gnome-42-2204
gnome-extension-manager
gtk-common-themes
kf5-5-106-qt-5-15-9-core22
snap-store
snapd
snapd-desktop-integration
vlc
 
   --- Installed Flatpak Package List:
Flatpak is not installed
 
Currently logged in User(s):
NAME     LINE         TIME             COMMENT
kostya   seat0        2023-06-15 11:42 (login screen)
kostya   tty2         2023-06-15 11:42 (tty2)
 
The User running this script was: kostya
uid=1000(kostya)
gid=1000(kostya)
groups=1000(kostya),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),
100(users),118(lpadmin)
 
The 'system-info' script was booted from an installed system
 
The 'system-info' script seems to be running locally
 
The Linux Kernel Command Line use to boot was: 
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-6.2.0-20-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
 
---- Required Programs For Report.
    --- Some Programs This Script Uses Were Missing --- 
    pastebinit
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the SSD and now suspend works!